# How to use a function over an RDD and get new column (Pyspark)?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

I'm looking for a way to apply a function to an RDD using PySpark and put the result in a new column. With DataFrames, it looks easy :
Given :

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([(u'1751940903', u'2014-06-19', '2016-10-19'), (u'_guid_VubEgxvPPSIb7W5caP-lXg==', u'2014-09-10', '2016-10-19')])
```

My code can look like this :

```
df= rdd.toDF(['gigya', 'inscription','d_date'])
df.show()
+--------------------+-------------------------+----------+
|               gigya|              inscription|    d_date|
+--------------------+-------------------------+----------+
|          1751940903|               2014-06-19|2016-10-19|
|_guid_VubEgxvPPSI...|               2014-09-10|2016-10-19|
+--------------------+-------------------------+----------+
```

Then :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, udf, col
get_period_day = udf(lambda item : datetime.strptime(item, "%Y-%m-%d").timetuple().tm_yday)

df.select('d_date', 'gigya', 'inscription', get_period_day(col('d_date')).alias('period_day')).show()

+----------+--------------------+-------------------------+----------+
|    d_date|               gigya|inscription_service_6Play|period_day|
+----------+--------------------+-------------------------+----------+
|2016-10-19|          1751940903|               2014-06-19|       293|
|2016-10-19|_guid_VubEgxvPPSI...|               2014-09-10|       293|
+----------+--------------------+-------------------------+----------+
```

Is there a way to do the same thing without the need to convert my RDD to a DataFrame ? Something with map for exemple..

This code can just give me a part from the expected results :

```
rdd.map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[1], '%Y-%m-%d').timetuple().tm_yday).cache().collect()
```

Help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
rdd.map(lambda x:
  x + (datetime.strptime(x[1], '%Y-%m-%d').timetuple().tm_yday, ))
```

or:

```
def g(x):
    return x + (datetime.strptime(x[1], '%Y-%m-%d').timetuple().tm_yday, )

rdd.map(g)
```

Comment: LostInOverflow : Thank you ! You rock !